# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SystemSettings_GetFont'

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I tried to run this following file below, but it did not work. It normaly has to display a graphic user interface built with the library wxPython.

```
import wx

class GoToClass(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(390, 350))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

    font = wx.SystemSettings_GetFont(wx.SYS_SYSTEM_FONT)
    font.SetPointSize(9)

    vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    hbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    st1 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, 'Class Name')
    st1.SetFont(font)
    hbox1.Add(st1, 0, wx.RIGHT, 8)
    tc = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1)
    hbox1.Add(tc, 1)
    vbox.Add(hbox1, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT | wx.TOP, 10)

    vbox.Add((-1, 10))

    hbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    st2 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, 'Matching Classes')
    st2.SetFont(font)
    hbox2.Add(st2, 0)
    vbox.Add(hbox2, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP, 10)

    vbox.Add((-1, 10))

    hbox3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    tc2 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
    hbox3.Add(tc2, 1, wx.EXPAND)
    vbox.Add(hbox3, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT | wx.EXPAND, 10)

    vbox.Add((-1, 25))

    hbox4 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    cb1 = wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, 'Case Sensitive')
    cb1.SetFont(font)
    hbox4.Add(cb1)
    cb2 = wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, 'Nested Classes')
    cb2.SetFont(font)
    hbox4.Add(cb2, 0, wx.LEFT, 10)
    cb3 = wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, 'Non-Project classes')
    cb3.SetFont(font)
    hbox4.Add(cb3, 0, wx.LEFT, 10)
    vbox.Add(hbox4, 0, wx.LEFT, 10)

    vbox.Add((-1, 25))

    hbox5 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    btn1 = wx.Button(panel, -1, 'Ok', size=(70, 30))
    hbox5.Add(btn1, 0)
    btn2 = wx.Button(panel, -1, 'Close', size=(70, 30))
    hbox5.Add(btn2, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.BOTTOM , 5)
    vbox.Add(hbox5, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.RIGHT, 10)

    panel.SetSizer(vbox)
    self.Centre()
    self.Show(True)

app = wx.App()
GoToClass(None, -1, 'Go To Class')
app.MainLoop()
```

This is the whole message error.
It says that the error comes from the line 12, the attribute `SystemSettings_GetFont` cannot be found.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/Test_wxPython/GotoClass.py", line 68, in <module>
    GoToClass(None, -1, 'Go To Class')
  File "C:/Python34/Test_wxPython/GotoClass.py", line 12, in __init__
    font = wx.SystemSettings_GetFont(wx.SYS_SYSTEM_FONT)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SystemSettings_GetFont'`

Comment: Why do you think that attribute exists?

Comment: This attribute `SystemSettings_GetFont` must be found in wxPython library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you are using python3.4 you are using phoenix.
Wxpython phoenix changed
SystemSettings_GetFont
to
SystemSettings.GetFont

Comment: For more details about differences between Phoenix and Classic wxPython, the Migration Guide is located here: http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/MigrationGuide.html